# Square register API removed oauth flow, how to initiate oauth using the register API

Tags: square-connect

Since register API removed oauth flow, what is the best way to initiate the square oauth flow using the register API for my android application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to initiate the OAuth flow just like you would for a web application. Give your users a link to `https://connect.squareup.com/oauth2/authorize?<PARAMETERS>` for them to click on. This could say "Connect to Square", be a button or whatever makes sense for your application.

See more info here: 
https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/oauth/#oauthflowrequestpermission